# MYSQL: How to SELECT the highest occurance from a column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with a list of films. I would like to display the film with the highest number of votes or occurrences on a webpage using php.How can i do that?

```
title
Toy Story 3
Toy Story 3
Toy Story 3
Inception
Inception
```

For example: the value that should be displayed will be Toy Story 3

Comment: @Konerak: Right, I missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
select title, count(*) as cnt from films group by title order by cnt desc limit 1
```

Comment: Add `limit 1` on the end to get just the one film, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT title, count(*) as count
FROM films
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will count the number of rows for each title and return the highest title only. Remove the limit if you want all titles returned sorted by the maximum number of titles.

This query will return something like:

```
+-------------+-------+
| title       | count |
+-------------+-------+
| Toy Story 3 |     3 |
+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Akki, don't forget to upvote the question and answer that was most helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT title,COUNT(title) AS cnt
 FROM Film
 GROUP BY title
 HAVING cnt=(SELECT COUNT(title) as count
              FROM Film
             GROUP BY title
             ORDER BY count desc limit 1);
```

This one will return all the films that happen to share the maximum count.

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.title, f.cnt as count 
from
( select title, count(*) as cnt
from films f
group by title ) f
, ( select max(count(*)) mcnt
FROM films 
GROUP BY title ) f2
where f.cnt = f2.mcnt
```

this one will return all the films that happen to share the maximum count

Answer (score 0):

In all the above answers given, apart from the expectation, one column is displayed in excess. It is expected only the "title" column to be returned but not the total count(occurance) column.

```
SELECT title
FROM film
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(title) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

So the result would be,

> **Grouping** by title
>
> > **Ordering** by Occurance of title in descending order
> >
> > > **Limiting** the result set to 1

```
+-------------+
| title       |
+-------------+
| Toy Story 3 |
+-------------+
```